# Filter mailing list messages differently if I am cc'd

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I filter all the emails from mailing list attaching a label and skipping the inbox, however I would like to see emails in my inbox if I'm CC'd.

Is it possible? Now I have a CC label but it makes the flow a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your original filter to include

```
-cc:me
```

in the "Has the words" line.

That way, the filter will act is it has been *except* if your email address is in the CC field.

Comment: Good point ale, the only downside I can see is that the filter won't apply the label

Comment: You might need to have two filters.